# What happens to my pointers when I initialize paging? C kernel dev

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, kernel, paging

I'm writing a kernel from scratch and am confused about what will happen once I initialize paging and map my kernel to a different location in virtual memory. My kernel is loaded to physical address `0x100000` on startup but I plan on mapping it to the virtual address `0xC0100000` so I can leave virtual address `0x100000` available for VM86 processes (more specifically, I plan on mapping physical addresses `0x100000` through `0x40000000` to virtual addresses `0xC0100000` through `0xFFFFF000`). Anyway, I have a bitmap to keep track of my page frames located at physical address `0x108000` with the address stored in a `uint32_t` pointer. My question is, what will happen to this pointer when I initialize paging? Will it still point to my bitmap located at physical address `0x108000` or will it point to whatever the virtual address `0x108000` is mapped to in my page table? If the latter is true, how do I get around the problem that my pointers will not be correct once paging is enabled? Will I have to update my pointers or am I going about this completely wrong?

Comment: Have you tested it somehow? Why would it point to the previous content if it stores the address `0x108000` which now *points* to a different physical place? I don't understand your question really, because AFAIK it seems clear what is going to happen.

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about resolving this then, should I just update the pointer after the fact? I'm just curious if there is a **right** way to do this.

Comment: A pointer with the value of `0x108000` points to whatever is at address `0x108000`. If you change what's at that address, then you've changed what the pointer points to.

Comment: Please show the relevant code.